# AngularJS: Directive - Passing strings without having to use quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here's a directive I created:

HTML:

```
<p-test something="'bla'"></p-test>
```

JavaScript:

```
.directive('pTest', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            something: '=?'
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/testTemplate.html',
        controller: 'testController'
    };
});
```

I'd like to be able to pass 'bla' as a string without the '', in the following way:

```
<p-test something="bla"></p-test>
```

I know it's possible via the attributes parameter in link, but it's irrelevant in this case (correct me if I'm wrong) as I'm passing these parameters directly to scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *I'd like to be able to pass 'bla' as a string without the '', in the following way:*

You would just need text binding (`@`) binding for that, instead of 2 way binding.

```
.directive('pTest', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            something: '@?' //<-- Here
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/testTemplate.html',
        controller: 'testController'
    };
});
```

and with the text binding if you want to bind scope properties then use interpolation. i.e example if bla is a scope variable holding a string then just do:

```
 <p-test something="{{bla}}"></p-test>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z8iS723SSaK3uJwMfse1?p=preview)**

Comment: Had to wait 10 minutes to do it then forgot. There you go.

Comment: Thank you! know I can give values to the in-template elements!